# <input #box pattern=" "> How do I make this work

Tags: angular, ionic4

Need to add pattern to my input. But the input type is `#box` and it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
            <div class="input" >
             <input #box pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}">
              <ion-button type="submit" (click)="saveWeight(box.value); clicked=true;" [disabled]="clicked">Submit</ion-button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use reactive forms Validators it'll work.

Comment: @GavishiddappaGadagi Thanks alot one more question. now i want the submit button to be disabled if the form is invalid which i do,AND after the click to disable it again 
 thats what i mean:

<ion-button [disabled]="!weightForm.valid" type="submit" (click)="saveWeight(); clicked=true;" [disabled]="clicked" >Submit</ion-button>

i tried this too:
<ion-button [disabled]="!weightForm.valid && clicked " type="submit" (click)="saveWeight(); clicked=true;">Submit</ion-button>

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the **type** attribute as well. 
Example:

```html
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
```

Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: No. The `type` attribute is optional. The default value for it is `text`. This makes no difference in HTML.

Comment: You are right, `type` is optional. However, the `pattern` attribute seems to be working as expected. Here is a working example with HTML and Reactive form: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjszzb